# Stored procedure doesn't insert into table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure in a database which is called AddNewStudent:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddNewStudent(
    @fName nvarchar(20),
    @sName nvarchar(20),
    @lName nvarchar(20),
    @faculty nvarchar(10),
    @specialty nvarchar(50),
    @OKS smallint,
    @StudentStat smallint,
    @fak nvarchar(50),
    @Course smallint,
    @Porok nvarchar(5),
    @Group int
    )
    AS
    INSERT INTO [Students] (FirstName, SecondName, LastName, Faculty,
    Specialty, OKS, StudentStatus, FakNumber, Course, Potok, [[Group]]])
    VALUES (@fName , @sName, @lName, @faculty, @specialty, @OKS,
    @StudentStat, @fak, @Course, @Porok, @Group)
    RETURN 2;
```

When i test the procedure through DatabaseExplorer (VS2013) everything is OK and the record is inserted into the table. But when i call the procedure in c# nothing happens. Bellow is the code for the method which I use to call the procedure:

```
    public static bool InsertStudent (Student student)
    {
        StudentDataClassesDataContext dc = new StudentDataClassesDataContext();
        try
        {
           int returnValue = dc.AddNewStudent(student.FirstName, student.SecondName, student.LastName, student.Faculty, student.Specialty, student.OKS, student.StudentStatus,
                student.FakNumber, student.Course, student.Potok, student._Group_);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Return Value : " + returnValue, "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception : " + e.Message, "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The returned value is 2 which means that the procedure does its work but why there is no record inserted into the table? I read that dc.SubmitChanges() is used instead of Commit.

Comment: Do you see message box with `Return Value: 2`?

Comment: What **connection string** are you using?

Comment: Did you COMMIT at the end of your stored proc?

Comment: configure your database from SSME and then connect it through your server explorer ,it will work . I encountered same problem while creating a window based project in .net so thats d way i get rid of it ..try it

Comment: Hamlet Hakobyan : Yes, I receive 2 as return Value and i see it in the message box 

 marc_s : I don't use connection string beacuse i use DataContext to make the connection

 Ramie : I don't commit, but when calling the procedure from the database i also don't commit      
 but the record is inserted. Also doesn't dc.SubmitChanges() do the commit ?

 SKT : Can you tell me how to configure my database from SSME ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was OK with the code. The issue was something with the links between the database and the project itself.

Comment: care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can start Sqlserver Profiler to see what happens, to see if there is any transaction start without commit? 
Also you can set a break point just after dc.submitchanges() and when your application hits break point, go to sql server and run this query

```
Select * from [Students] with (nolock)
```

and be sure that the data is in your table, after that continue running your application and run that query again, if the data was in your table and no it's gone there is an uncommited transaction. to solve that just use TransactionScope. if data is not in your table from the start you might running your code on another database. You can pass the connnctionstring in datacontext constructor.

Comment: Hi RezaRahmati, thanks for your answer.

I did set a break point just after dc.submitchanges() and i checked the database but no record was inserted.

I tried with another method, but the result was the same - no record was inserted. However when it comes to select query from the database it returns information. Can it be something wrong with privileges? Bellow is the new method I used. As you can see I tried with TransactionScope but nothing changed

Comment: Just for being sure did you set `with(nolock)` in your query after `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` since your data is in transaction the data wont show up until commiting the transaction unless you use `with(nolock)`

Comment: No, I haven't set `with(nolock)` in my query. Isn't scope.Complete() commiting the transaction?

Comment: I mean when you hit the break point (as I mentioned before ) the transaction is not committed yet and for checking if the record really is in table or not you have to use `with(nolock)` to fetch dirty records too. Because I was wondering that you said you have check the db and there was no record inserted at the break point

Comment: Also you can send me the sql profiler trace, to see what is going on (since your code seems to be right)